# How does the data parameter works with this function?

Tags: javascript

I wanted to modify this code into typescript because I don't know how to make a type definition file for this project (@types)

[jsHue Repo](https://github.com/blargoner/jshue/blob/master/src/jshue.js)

Here's the problem,
I see there's a method for example (setLightState) where it takes in an ID and calls a network request.

But in the documentation, it also passes in another argument for HTTP Body request.

In documentation:

```
user.setLightState(3, { bri: 128 })
```

So I was wondering where does the second argument comes from in the js lib.

The function of setLightState(), from my understanding setLightState, takes in a method and id then returns the url function

```
setLightState: _parametrize(_put, id => `${_lightUrl(id)}/state`)
```

And the _parametrized function confused me a lot

```
var _parametrize = (method, url) => (p, ...rest) => method(url(p), ...rest);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's no surprise you are finding this confusing. This code is excessively abstracted and has poor variable names.

Let's try to make sense of `setLightState` by undoing some of the abstraction.
The following four lines of code all have the same result (just more hard coded):

`setLightState: _parametrize(_put, id =>`${_lightUrl(id)}/state`)`

`setLightState: (p, ...rest) => _put(`${_lightUrl(p)}/state`, ...rest)`

`setLightState: (p, ...rest) => (_requestJson.bind(null, 'PUT'))(`${_lightUrl(p)}/state`, ...rest)`

`setLightState: (p, ...rest) => _requestJson('PUT',`${_lightUrl(p)}/state`, ...rest)`

So when you call `setLightState(3, { bri: 128 })`, the `{ bri: 128 }` goes to `...rest` and ends up being the `data` parameter passed to the `_requestJson` function.

I hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you for responding, It clears my confusion now. Appreciate your help :)